# Is it true that all primes $n<p<2n, \; p<2n-1$ are members of odd Goldbach partitions of $2n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

By Bertrand's Postulate, there is at least on prime $p$ such that

$$n<p<2n, \quad n>1$$

The question is: Is it true that all primes $n<p<2n, \; p< 2n-1$  are members of odd Goldbach partitions of $2n+1$?

For instance, let be $n=9$, the primes by Bertrand's postulate are: 11, 13, 17.

Therefore,

$$19 = 11 + 5 + 3$$
$$19 = 13 + 3 + 3$$

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect to this when Goldbach's conjecture is still open?

Comment: Well, it implies Goldbach strong conjecture, however from different prospective. It doesn't say that all evens are sum of two primes, but only asks the relation between Bertrand's postulate and ternary Goldbach conjecture :) I expected that this question was already discussed in literature or on SO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any answer to this question is equivalent to solving Goldbach's strong conjecture.

Suppose the answer is YES. Then for any even integer $2k > 2$, take an odd prime $p < 2k$, and let $n = k + \frac{p-1}{2}$. Then $n < p < 2n-1$, so an answer of YES would imply that there's a ternary Goldbach partition of $2n+1$ containing $p$. But $2n+1 = 2k + p$, giving us a binary Goldbach partition of $2k$.

Suppose the answer is NO. Then for some $n$, there is some prime $p$ with $n < p < 2n-1$ such that $p$ is not a member of a Goldbach partition of $2n+1$. That means that $2n+1-p$ is an even integer which is not the sum of two primes.

Comment: I just want to comment out the block YES. The ternary Goldbach conjecture is proved by H. A. Helfgott in 2013, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.7748

Thanks for the answer

Comment: I've added a better answer that reduces either option to the strong Goldbach conjecture, to resolve this ambiguity, though I'm not 100% sure of the status of Helfgott's proof.

Comment: Strong Goldbach is weak Goldbach with one of the primes being 3 ...